# Flutter radio button won't rebuild

Tags: flutter, radio-button

I have a problem with this code, the variable inside a radio changes but the radio probably won't rebuild because the dot doesn't move when I tap it. But after that, if I tap on language choice again, the last chosen language has a dot. It's probably some State problem, but I don't know how to fix it. Tried another approach, as in the row with the Spanish language, also doesn't work.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';
 import 'package:settings_ui/settings_ui.dart';


class SettingsPR extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsPRState createState() => _SettingsPRState();
}

class _SettingsPRState extends State<SettingsPR> {
  int _radioValue = 1;

  int _radioHandler(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _radioValue = value;
      switch (_radioValue) {
        case 0:
          return _radioValue;
          break;
        case 1:
          return _radioValue;
          break;
        case 2:
          return _radioValue;
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: SettingsList(
      sections: [
        SettingsSection(title: 'Common', tiles: [
          SettingsTile(
            title: 'Language',
            subtitle: 'English',
            leading: Icon(Icons.language),
            onTap: () {
              Alert(
                  context: context,
                  title: 'Edit',
                  content: Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: new Radio(
                            value: 0,
                            groupValue: _radioValue,
                            onChanged: _radioHandler,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'English',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: new Radio(
                            value: 1,
                            groupValue: _radioValue,
                            onChanged: (value) =>
                                setState(() => _radioValue = value),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Spanish',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: new Radio(
                            value: 2,
                            groupValue: _radioValue,
                            onChanged: _radioHandler,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Polish',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ]),
                  buttons: [
                    DialogButton(
                        onPressed: () =>
                            Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                                .pop(true),
                        child: Text(
                          "OK",
                          style: TextStyle(),
                        ))
                  ]).show();
            },
          ),
        ]),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, maybe it will help someone. I had to switch to AlertDialog and not use flutter_dialog library though. The solution was to put a StatefulBuilder inside the AlertDialog to create BuildContext, and everything worked.